# Load SWF files through YouTube

Tags: youtube, flash, embed, param

Would it be possible to embed an external SWF file with a YouTube video/SWF?

For example: `http://www.youtube.com/player2.swf?LoadExternalSwf=http://www.pylon.ca/main.swf`

Answer (score 2):

No. Cross-domain data is not permitted by the configuration in http://www.youtube.com/crossdomain.xml